# Can not deploy create-react-app with token

Tags: reactjs, git, github, deployment, access-token

I have been trying to deploy create-react-app, but got an error

```
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/charyyev2000/Portfolio-React.git/' not found
```

then I created a **token** and tried to deploy with that,

```
git remote add origin https://<TOKEN>@github.com/charyyev2000/Portfolio-React.git
```

again got an error;

Deleted repository, created again and tried to deploy, again got the same error

```
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/charyyev2000/Portfolio-React.git/' not found
```

What did I do wrong? or, is there something wrong with my homepage in `packages.json`?

```
"homepage": "https://charyyev2000.github.io/Portfolio-React",
```

I cant deploy from any other of my repositories too.
What should I do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are new comer in Git/GitHub tools, I hope you can done this task.

Your remote repository URL is https://github.com/charyyev2000/Portfolio-React

Solution 1:
Create a new repository on the command line

```
echo "# Portfolio-React" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/charyyev2000/Portfolio-React.git
git push -u origin main
```

Solution 2: (I think you will prefer this solution, because your source code is exist).

Push an existing repository from the command line

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/charyyev2000/Portfolio-React.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

Let's follow the guide what you see likes this

[image]

P/S: Sometime, you need

```
git add .
git commit -m"foo"
git push -v
```

or you see any guide on your console screen, let's follow guide what you see.

Comment: Thanks, man, second solution worked for me.
I have been using this steps:

Comment: I used to use these steps:
`git init`
`git add .`
`git commit -m 'upgrade'`
`git remote add origin https://github.com/charyyev2000/Portfolio-React.git`
git push -u origin main`
then added to homepage: 
`https://charyyev2000.github.io/repo-name`
the run command
`npm install gh-pages --save-dev`
added in to scripts in package.json:
`predeploy: npm run build`
`deploy: gh-pages -d build`
npm run deploy

could you please tell me what is the difference between this and  the solution you have provided?

Comment: **Solution 1:** You have GitHub repository before you have in local PC. **Solution 2:** You have source code at local PC, then make folder become local git repository, then you push to server. For simple, What born first: local or GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

Your repository is probably private.

Try this: `git remote set-url origin https://YOUR_GITHUB_USER@github.com/charyyev2000/Portfolio-React.git`

Or use an ssh key.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent&ved=2ahUKEwjoysreiIjzAhVwTTABHQPHDzIQFnoECGwQAQ&sqi=2&usg=AOvVaw2B_nuIizqk0LtbV4qWtzzH

Comment: no, it is not private.